# View automatically adjusting upon changing applications with Status Bar hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a `UIViewController` that is conditionally hiding the status bar in the application, but a problem I'm having is that when I have the status bar hidden and I change to a different application with a status bar, the view moves up 20 pixels to compensate for the missing status bar, even though I've already compensated for it.

I'm hiding the status bar like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and showing it again with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

I've also tried adding this to my hide:

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

and this to my show:

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:NO];
```

Why is my view adjusting automatically upon me switching applications?

Comment: Does this happen on iOS 5 and iOS 6, or only iOS 6?

Comment: Include how you are conditionally hiding/showing StatusBar, and how you are compensating for it. A complete code snippet for this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to compensate for the **StatusBar** being shown.

By default, the top 20px of your view will sit under the StatusBar.

When you `setStatusBarHidden:YES`, you don't need to move your view 20px up unless you already moved it 20px down when `setStatusBarHidden:NO`.